# Adding dynamic variables in object keys

Tags: javascript

Is something like this allowed in Javascript:

```
var object = {
    'key1' + var1 : 'value',
    'key2' + var1 : 'value'
};
```

I'd liked to concat the var1 variable with the key but I'm getting a syntax error. Here's the full error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +
```

Comment: When you are not sure if its ok or not, try it in the developer console.

Comment: @phylax Probably OP has tried, syntax errors don't occur without doing something wrong ; ).

Comment: This is relatively often asked question, just [pick your dup](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]dynamic+object+key)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, obviously(*You are getting an error*),

But you can do this:

```
var obj = {};
obj["key1" + var1] = 'value';
```

It's using bracket notation to set the dynamic so called key